# What is blocking the network connection? Unable to do a EJB lookup between Client-server WebSphere

Tags: tcp, websphere, ejb-3.0

I have disabled "Enable administrative security" on both client and server. Using Cport I can able to see the connection is established, but I am still getting Connection refused

Below is the client side log

```
18:34:49:235 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:236 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No]
[4/25/19 18:34:49:237 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1688)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:237 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1177)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:237 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1086)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:237 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:630)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:238 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:238 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:238 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:239 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:239 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:239 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:239 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.XXX.technology.ejbconnector.jWebsphere85Provider.lookupRemoteBean(jWebsphere85Provider.java:213)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:239 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.XXX.technology.ejbconnector.jWebsphere85Provider.getRemoteBean(jWebsphere85Provider.java:188)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:240 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     ... 47 more
[4/25/19 18:34:49:240 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E07  completed: No
[4/25/19 18:34:49:240 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1139)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:241 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1514)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:241 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1028)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:241 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1480)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:241 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1658)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:241 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1436)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:242 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:242 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:242 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1685)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:242 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     ... 58 more
[4/25/19 18:34:49:243 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[4/25/19 18:34:49:243 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:244 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:244 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:244 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:244 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:244 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:403)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:355)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:437)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:182)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:245 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:98)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:246 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:134)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:246 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:230)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:246 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1740)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:246 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1765)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:246 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1050)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:247 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1135)
[4/25/19 18:34:49:247 IST] 000000ba SystemErr     R     ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was working fine before you enabled security, the likely cause is that your client is not configured correctly to use SSL connections (which would now be required by the server), and is now trying to connect to a 0-port (turning on ORB trace would confirm this).  See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237101#ConnR, scenario #4.

Comment: I installed the profile with "localhost", ppl suggested me to reinstall with full domain or ip address. so did it and it resolved this issue. In such case, we can try tracert command